# PowerShell .NET Retrieve only parent node if all child nodes are selected

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, powershell

I would like to know how it's possible to only retrieve the parent node's name when all of it's child nodes are selected. In the code below, the function `Get-CheckedNodes` retrieves everything with a check-mark in front of it.

In the example below, if you select 'Cars > Blue' it will return: Lamborghini, Maserati and Blue. This is correct, but I would only like to have it report the parent 'Blue' because everything is selected. However, when there's only one car selected, it should report back just that one car and not it's parent.

**The code:**

```
Function Add-Node($Nodes, $Path) {  
    $Path.Split("/") | % {
        Write-Verbose "Searching For: $_"
        $SearchResult = $Nodes.Find($_, $False)

    If ($SearchResult.Count -eq 1) {
      Write-Verbose "Selecting: $($SearchResult.Name)"
      $Nodes = $SearchResult[0].Nodes
    }
    Else {
      Write-Verbose "Adding: $_"
      $Node = New-Object Windows.Forms.TreeNode($_)
      $Node.Name = $_
      $Nodes.Add($Node)  | Out-Null
    }
  }
}

Function Get-CheckedNodes($nodes) {
    foreach ($n in $Nodes) {
        if ($n.nodes.count -gt 0) {
            Get-CheckedNodes $n.nodes
        }
        if ($n.checked) {
            Write-Output $n.Name
        }           
    }   
}

Function Select-ChildNodes($node) {
    $checkStatus = $node.Checked
    foreach ($n in $node.Nodes) {
        $n.checked = $checkstatus
        Select-ChildNodes($n)
    }
}

Function Select-ParentNode($node) {
    $parent = $node.Parent
    if($parent -eq $null) {
        return
    }
    $parent.checked = $true
    foreach ($n in $parent.Nodes) {
        if(!$n.checked) {
            $parent.Checked = $false
            break
        }  
    }
    Select-ParentNode($parent)
}

$script:SelectedOU = $null

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '342, 502'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

$ButtonOK_Click = {
    if ($script:SelectedOU = Get-CheckedNodes $treeView.Nodes) {
        $Form.close()
    }
    elseif (([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
                "You haven't selected anything.`nAre you sure you want to leave?", 
                "Oops!",'YesNo','Information')) -eq 'Yes') {$Form.close()}
}

$Treeview_AfterCheck = {
    $Treeview.Remove_AfterCheck($Treeview_AfterCheck)
    Select-ChildNodes($_.node)
    Select-ParentNode($_.node)
    $Treeview.Add_AfterCheck($Treeview_AfterCheck)
}

$TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$TreeView.Dock = 'Fill'
$TreeView.CheckBoxes = $true
$Treeview.Add_AfterCheck($Treeview_AfterCheck)

Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Fruits"  
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Vegetables"  
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars" 
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Blue" 
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Blue/Lamborghini"
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Blue/Maserati"
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Red" 
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Red/Lamborghini"
Add-Node $TreeView.Nodes "Cars/Red/Maserati"

$ButtonCancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonCancel.text = “&Cancel”
$ButtonCancel.Location = '120,467'
$ButtonCancel.size = '75,23'
$ButtonCancel.Anchor = 'Bottom, Left'
$ButtonCancel.add_Click({$Form.close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonCancel)

$ButtonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonOK.Location = '245,467'
$ButtonOK.Size = '75,23'
$ButtonOK.Name = 'ButtonOK'
$ButtonOK.Text = 'OK'
$ButtonOK.add_Click($ButtonOK_Click)
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonOK)
$Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)
$Form.ShowDialog() > $null

$script:SelectedOU
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to add an extra check looking for something not checked at the current level prior to writing the node's Text, this occurs only in the Get-CheckedNodes function.

So if at least one node in the current level is not checked, then the ones checked are written to the output, else nothing is. And since if all nodes are checked in the current level, the parent will be checked and it's text will be written to the output. In addition, if a node is checked, then all its child nodes will be. So this should work in all cases.

```
Function Get-CheckedNodes($nodes) {

    $allChecked = $true
    foreach ($n in $Nodes) 
    {
        if (!$n.checked) {
            $allChecked = $false
            break
        }
    }
    foreach ($n in $Nodes) 
    {
        if ($n.nodes.count -gt 0) {
            Get-CheckedNodes $n.nodes
        }
        if ($n.checked -and $allChecked -eq $false) {
            Write-Output $n.Name
        }           
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your approach is a lot better and easier to read then my efforts were. I was trying to create a counter that counts the total nodes for the current node. Then after this check if the current node has nodes and if not increment the counter. But I couldn't get it to work properly. Thank you again Micky for this great solution! Works like a dream :)